# Database First update other developer database

Tags: c#, database

How I can migrate other developer database changes to my local database in Database first approve in visual studio.

Comment: Are you talking about DDL changes or data changes?

Answer (score 1):

I normally use SQL Server Tools in Visual Studio, you can compare and sync schema's using that. If you're missing it, go back to the installer and activate it.

```
Tools | SQL Server | New Data Comparison
Tools | SQL Server | New Schema Comparison
```

It will create a SQL file for you, or you can click to sync (not really recommended but works if you're careful!)